# Are Go HTML template file extension names arbitrary?

Tags: go, template-engine

I see different people naming HTML files `index.html` or `index.tmpl`. Both seem to work the same, what's the difference? I see no official documentation about it. Can extension names just be chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: This question is similar to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254013/whats-the-proper-file-extension-or-abbr-for-golangs-text-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file parsing [function](https://godoc.org/html/template#ParseFiles) and [method](https://godoc.org/html/template#Template.ParseFiles) expect full file names. The template package does not impose any restrictions or make any assumptions about the extensions used in the file names.

Comment: Using an different extension allow you to block direct template access with your web server configuration.